# Присваивание обработчика в функции

Tags: javascript

```
var add_the_hendlers = function(node) { 
    var i; 
    for(i = 0; i < node.length; i++) { 
        node[i].onclick = function() { 
            console.log(i) 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Проблема в том , что console.log всегда возвращает последний инкремент, то есть на странице к примеру 3 дива, и при нажатии на них, всегда выводится 3, я знаю что нужно использовать замыкания, мол там хранится ссылка на переменную, но почему в данном случае так получается ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var add_the_hendlers = function(node) { 
  var i; 
  for(i = 0; i < node.length; i++) { 
    (function(j) {
      node[j].onclick = function() { 
        console.log(j) 
      };
    })(i);
  } 
}
```

В этом случае переменная будет скопирована в область видимости замыкания. При этом контекст останется верным (в отличии от `bind`)

Comment: классическое решение :-) в идеале стоило бы название параметра поменять, а то сейчас слишком много `i` :-D

Comment: Да, я именно за него т.к. мне кажется это не тот случай где `bind` нужен, тем более вопрос похож на те, что дают на собеседовании, обычно там ожидают именно такой ответ. Поменял)

Comment: Для общих знаний вполне и bind подойдет, только я бы все-таки не на _this_ а на первый параметр делал

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) { 
    node[i].onclick = function(event) {
        console.log(+this,event.target); 
    }.bind(i); 
}
```

Comment: плохое решение: `i` в _this_ - станет объектом, а не примитивным числом

Comment: Какой ужас. Его можно превратить в число одним символом

Comment: Конечно :-) если знать что там будет объект, а не рассчитывать на примитив :-)

Comment: Кроме того, в вашем случае теряется ссылка на сам элемент по которому щелкнули

Comment: `arguments[0].target` (добавил в ответ)

Comment: Уже похоже на правду :-)

Comment: Не знаю, от `+this` мне делается плохо :)

Comment: @AleksanderK., все зависит от того, как это будет использоваться. `1+this` например, при сложении с числом, вполне ничего смотрится

Comment: @AleksanderK. Вам становится плохо от слова this (как мне) или от унарного плюса, или от их комбинации?

Comment: @Grundy тут можно `var i = +this` внутри обработчика, для полного счастья. И это будет работать

Comment: @Darth, а никто не говорил, что не будет :-) я ж говорю все зависит от того как задумывалось использовать эту переменную

Comment: @Darth От комбинации, this подразумевает объект - контекст или ссылку на объект события. В простом примере - это не так критично. Но представим, что новичок решит использовать это повсеместно - в результате не ожидаемое поведение и головная боль для всех.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. на момент клика по элементу у вас уже прошел цикл for и i стал равен 3, поэтому на момент клика вы видите последний инкремент. Воспользуйтесь функцией .bind для сохранения нужного контекста.

```
var add_the_hendlers = function(node) { 
    var i; 
    for(i = 0; i < node.length; i++) { 
        node[i].onclick = function() {
            console.log(this); 
        }.bind(i); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: код неверен - в момент выполнения `i` = **уже** равно 3, поэтому нет смысла 3 присваивать переменной x :-D

Comment: Прошу прощения, поправил код.

Comment: _console.log(this);_ выведет объект, а не примитив. Тот же недочет, что был в соседнем ответе. Чтобы не повторяться, лучше пропихнуть его как параметр

Comment: Кроме того, в вашем случае теряется ссылка на сам элемент по которому щелкнули

Comment: Согласен, не надо затирать this, тем более this это объект и пытаться присвоить ему простое значение - плохой подход.